# Parse a simple 2d Array string to Java 2d String Array

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, 2d

I have this simple json string of two dimensional(2d) arrays and want to convert to JAVA 2d String Array like `String[][]`.

**String**

```
"[ [\"case1\",[\"case1-a\"]], [\"case2\",[\"case2-a\",\"case2-b\",\"case2-c\"]] ]"
```

What is the simplest way to do that ? Been googling around but couldn't find a simple solution. Appreciate any help !

Comment: You could use regex. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html
Here is a good example how to use it

Comment: No RegExp. I'm looking for a simple json parser.

Comment: The example you provided looks to me more like a map. Also look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: No its not a map, as i mentioned it is a simple string of nested 2d/3d arrays

Comment: https://code.google.com/archive/p/quick-json/ Quick Json Parser is good for that but i think you must edit the string a bit

Comment: @GURU-MVG was your question [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably cleaner ways of doing this with a modern JSON library, but since this way may be easier to understand, I am demonstrating how to do it step by step with the older "Simple JSON" library:

```
package samplejava;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;

public class JsonTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONArray rows = (JSONArray) JSONValue.parse("[ [\"case1\",[\"case1-a\"]], [\"case2\",[\"case2-a\",\"case2-b\",\"case2-c\"]] ]");   
    System.out.println("Before: " + rows.toJSONString());
    String[][] result = new String[rows.size()][];
    for(int row = 0; row < rows.size(); row++) {
        JSONArray cols = (JSONArray)((JSONArray) rows.get(row)).get(1);
        String[] temp = new String[cols.size()];
        for(int col=0; col < cols.size(); col++) {
            temp[col] = cols.get(col).toString();
        }
        result[row] = temp;
    }
    System.out.println("After: " + Arrays.deepToString(result));   
}
}
```

**Output:**

> Before: [["case1",["case1-a"]],["case2",["case2-a","case2-b","case2-c"]]]
>
> After: [[case1-a], [case2-a, case2-b, case2-c]]